# Python Tornado Backend, WebSocket Listener and MQTT Client at the same time

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, mqtt, tornado

I wanted to ask you if it's possible to run a MQTT Client and Listen to WebSocket at the same time with the Python Backend Framework Tornado.

My goal is to create a MQTT Client which sends a WebSocket with the received Message from the MQTT Broker to a React frontend.

But my first step is to successfully run MQTT Client and WebSocket on the Backend.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a minimal reproducible example. For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with a new Thread

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

 thread = Thread(target = mqtt_set)
 thread.start()

 application = tornado.web.Application([
 (r"/websocket", EchoWebSocket),
 (r"/main", MainHandler),
 ])

 application.listen(8888)
 tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```